# How to compare two JSON files that adhere to a schema?

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have JSON (for Ignition SCADA) that defines "tags" in the system which essentially defines a tree structure where the end tree nodes are the tags themselves with the configuration that defines them, and the sub-tree elements being folders. Each folder has a key called "tags" which holds a list of any tags or folders that are contained within them.

The most important parts of the JSON that defines a tag is its path which is made up of each "name" field in the JSON along the Folder path it lies in, similar to a filepath of a file. Elements of the path are separated by "/" e.g. for TagA below, its tag path would be "StackOverflow/FolderA/TagA".

Below is the tree in the Ignition designer:

[image: Tags Displayed in Ignition Tag Browser GUI]

Below is the JSON that represents these tags:

```
{
  "name": "StackOverflow",
  "tagType": "Folder",
  "tags": [
    {
      "name": "FolderA",
      "tagType": "Folder",
      "tags": [
        {
          "valueSource": "memory",
          "dataType": "Int8",
          "name": "TagA",
          "tooltip": "This is tag a",
          "value": 15,
          "tagType": "AtomicTag",
          "engUnit": "%"
        },
        {
          "valueSource": "memory",
          "dataType": "Int8",
          "name": "TagB",
          "tooltip": "This is tag b",
          "value": 98,
          "tagType": "AtomicTag",
          "engUnit": "%"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

If I make changes to these tags/folders by:

- adding a new tag, `StackOverflow/FolderA/TagC`
- change value of `StackOverflow/FolderA/TagA.tooltip`
- change value of `StackOverflow/FolderA/TagA.value`
- delete `StackOverflow/FolderA/TagB`

I want to get a report of this as a list of changes that I can export into Excel, e.g. something like:

```
[{'tagpath': 'StackOverflow/FolderA/TagC', 'changedFrom': None, 'changedTo': 'added'},
{'tagpath': 'StackOverflow/FolderA/TagA.tooltip', 'changedFrom': 'This is tag a', 'changedTo': 'This is tag a with changes'},
{'tagpath': 'StackOverflow/FolderA/TagA.value', 'changedFrom': 15, 'changedTo': 59},
{'tagpath': 'StackOverflow/FolderA/TagB', 'changedFrom': None, 'changedTo': 'deleted'}
]
```

This is the changes JSON:

```
{
  "name": "StackOverflow",
  "tagType": "Folder",
  "tags": [
    {
      "name": "FolderA",
      "tagType": "Folder",
      "tags": [
        {
          "valueSource": "memory",
          "dataType": "Int8",
          "name": "TagC",
          "tooltip": "This is tag a with changes",
          "value": 59,
          "tagType": "AtomicTag",
          "engUnit": "%"
        },
        {
          "valueSource": "memory",
          "dataType": "Int8",
          "name": "TagA",
          "tooltip": "This is tag a with changes",
          "value": 59,
          "tagType": "AtomicTag",
          "engUnit": "%"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

What I'm not sure of is how best to compare these two files using Python. I can pull something together using simple for loops and comparing the json manually and keeping track of differences, but I was wondering if there is a better more sophisticated way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can be solved with [littletree](https://pypi.org/project/littletree/) (I'm the author).

Assuming the original and modified data are stored as a nested dict in `original` and `modified` respectively

```py
from littletree import Node

original_tree = Node.from_dict(original, identifier_name="name", children_name="tags")
modified_tree = Node.from_dict(modified, identifier_name="name", children_name="tags")

# Collect changes in a list
changes = []
for diff_node in original_tree.compare(modified_tree).iter_tree():
    diff_data = diff_node.data
    if not diff_data:
        continue  # Data was the same
    
    if "self" not in diff_data:
        changes.append({"tagpath": str(diff_node.path), "from": None, "to": "added"})
    elif "other" not in diff_data:
        changes.append({"tagpath": str(diff_node.path), "from": None, "to": "removed"})
    else:
        original_data, modified_data = diff_data["self"], diff_data["other"]
        for key, original_value in original_data.items():
            modified_value = modified_data[key]
            if original_value != modified_value:
                changes.append({"tagpath": f"{diff_node.path}.{key}",
                                "from": original_value,
                                "to": modified_value})

for change in changes:
    print(change)
```

The result looks like this:

```
{'tagpath': '/StackOverflow/FolderA/TagA.tooltip', 'from': 'This is tag a', 'to': 'This is tag a but changed'}
{'tagpath': '/StackOverflow/FolderA/TagA.value', 'from': 15, 'to': 16}
{'tagpath': '/StackOverflow/FolderA/TagB', 'from': None, 'to': 'removed'}
{'tagpath': '/StackOverflow/FolderA/TagC', 'from': None, 'to': 'added'}
```

Comment: This looks really cool, but when I'm running it, I'm not seeing the right results. This is what I'm getting:
```{'tagpath': '/StackOverflow/FolderA/TagA.tagType', 'from': 'Folder', 'to': 'AtomicTag'}
{'tagpath': '/StackOverflow/FolderA/TagB', 'from': None, 'to': 'removed'}
{'tagpath': '/StackOverflow/FolderA/TagC', 'from': None, 'to': 'added'}```

Comment: That was recently fixed, but I saw the fix was not yet released. I've just released it now.

Comment: That's awesome, I got it working now, thanks! :) I modified it a bit in the changes section as it doesn't handle keys that don't exist in the other, but that's about all I changed. Super cool, thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure where it's best to ask this question, but I'm wanting to use your library for another json schema diff. The `identifier_name` in this case is a sub-key of each node's `meta` prop e.g. `meta.name`. Is this possible to use?

Comment: Not sure where to ask either. Feel free to create a question on https://github.com/lverweijen/littletree/issues
It's not supported out of the box, but this might help:

```
def to_tree(data):
    """Identifiers are stored in node["meta"]["name"]."""
    identifier = data["meta"]["name"]
    children = [to_tree(child) for child in data.pop("tags", [])]
    return Node(data, identifier=identifier, children=children)
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, I'll give it a go when I get some more time - I'm rained out at the moment!

Answer (score 1):

May be some packages will be useful. If you don't want to use it, you can use iterator to instead for one by one.

```
from jsondiff import diff
json1 = {
    "name": "Bob",
    "age": 10,
    "sex": "male"
}
json2 = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "age": 10,
    "sex": "female"
}

difference1 = diff(json1, json2)
difference2 = diff(json2, json1)
print(difference1)
print(difference2)
```

result:
{'name': 'Alice', 'sex': 'female'}
{'name': 'Bob', 'sex': 'male'}

I think you can use this to construct your change log.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hmm, while this won't work for the comparing the whole JSON file, this sparked an idea: I never considered using this for each tag instead to at least get the tag-level diffs. I would then need to write my own diff functions to check if the tag was deleted/added, but that shouldn't be too bad. I'll give this a go, thanks